# How to move selected object to the curser location using a python command?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am trying to figure out a very simple python command to move the selected object(or move the object by name) to the cursor location. Anyone know the command to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cursor location is global**

The location of the cursor can be considered as "global coordinates".  The cursor has no parent. When the cursor location is set to zero, it sits at the scene origin.

An object's `location` is relative to its parent.  Its "global" or "world" transforms can be gleaned from `obj.matrix_world`.

To get an object in the scene by name

```
name = "Foo"
scene = context.scene
obj = scene.objects.get(name)
```

If there is no object named "Foo" `obj is None`

To move the object to the cursor location.

```
obj.matrix_world.translation = scene.cursor.location
```

To align both location and rotation to the cursor (*Note assumes `obj` has unit scale*)

```
obj.matrix_world = scene.cursor.matrix
```

Comment: this is not working for chidren (vertex parented)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a little function that copies the cursor's location and sets it for the active object.

```
import bpy


def snap_active_to_cursor(obj: bpy.types.Object, copy_rotation=False):
    cursor = bpy.context.scene.cursor
    active_object = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    active_object.location = cursor.location

    if copy_rotation:
        active_object.rotation_euler = cursor.rotation_euler

obj = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]         
snap_active_to_cursor(obj)
```

If you want to move all selected objects individually your function could look like this:

```
def snap_selected_to_cursor(copy_rotation=False):
    cursor = bpy.context.scene.cursor

    for obj in bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected:
        obj.location = cursor.location

        if copy_rotation:
            obj.rotation_euler = cursor.rotation_euler
```

---

Blender already has an operator with similar functionality, however it requires the 3D View as context. Since custom contexts are not worth the hassle for as simple task like this, I wouldn't use [`bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor) within scripts/add-ons when you only want to move the active object.

Comment: this is not working on children and especially for chidren (vertex parented)