# Python code to add objects to the 3D Cursor

Tags: python

Python code to add objects to the 3D Cursor

I added a cube and looked at the Python Console

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_ editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0)))
```

The code looked like this

When you run this code, it adds the cube to the first location you put it in, not the location of the 3D Cursor (location=(0, 0, 0))

I want to use this add-on, so the Python code has to be one line

https://github.com/InamuraJIN/CommandRecorder

How do I add an Object to the 3D Cursor's position?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Cursor belongs to `scene = context.scene` then in operator `location=scene.cursor.location`  or alternatively use `align='CURSOR'`  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/precisely-move-the-3d-cursor and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164734/how-to-move-selected-object-to-the-curser-location-using-a-python-command/164779#164779

Comment: Thank you.
I'm terrible at Python.The following code could not be executed
How should I describe it?

`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=scene.cursor.location`
and
`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, scene = context.scene, location=scene.cursor.location`

Comment: `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=bpy.context.scene.cursor.location)` or `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2,  align='CURSOR')`   Enter edit mode False is default. Defaults need not be included in call.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Now you can Add object to the cursor position
BTW, can I disable Cursor rotation?

Comment: Use first if only want to use location.  Can set cursor rotation to zero AFAIK can't disable it (could hide the UI)

Comment: It's done!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry.
I'm new to this site and I'm not sure
How can I rate you as the Best Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add new object at cursor**

Default values.

If you auto complete on the operator in the python console, it shows the properties and their default values.  There is no need to pass any default value to the operator.

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(0, 0, 0))
Construct a cube mesh
```

To add a cube with location and rotation of 3D cursor

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(align='CURSOR')
```

To add at  cursor location.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=bpy.context.scene.cursor.location)
```

or equivalently, align to cursor but override rotation.  Even though the zero rotation passed is default, just passing it (in tests so far) overrides cursor rotation.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(align='CURSOR', rotation=(0, 0, 0))
```

Related

[Precisely move the 3D cursor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/precisely-move-the-3d-cursor)

[How to move selected object to the curser location using a python command?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164734/how-to-move-selected-object-to-the-curser-location-using-a-python-command/164779#164779)

Comment: Very straightforward!
Thank you so much!

Comment: ```bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(align='CURSOR', rotation=(-90, 0, 0))```
If (0, 0, 0) the rotation of 3DCursor is ignored.
However, (-90, 0, 0) seems to add the rotation of 3DCursor and -90
What should I do?

Comment: Rotations in blender are radians.  360 degrees = 2 pi radians.

Comment: OK, I see.
It's hard to...
(1.5708, 0, 0) Is this correct?

Comment: close enough...

Comment: Thank you!!I think I got it!